# VS2010 keeps removing non-IE styles in CSS and downgrades verison from 3.0 to 2.1

Tags: css, visual-studio-2010

I have a webApp project in VS2010 that uses a seperate CSS set at version 3.0. There are styles in some classes that do not pertain to IE for cross browser compatibility which VS keeps removing. At some point while I am working with the project or CSS file (not those classes), it seems like its formatting the file and alters the classes and removes those styles. This keeps happening and I can't pin down what's causing it.

For example, the following class:

```
.label
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-align: right;
    color: black;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-left: .5em;

    background-color: #EBEBEB; /* Fallback background color for non supported browsers */  
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#FFFFFF), to(#DAD6E7));  
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF, #DAD6E7);  
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF, #DAD6E7);  
    background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF, #DAD6E7);  
    background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF, #DAD6E7);  
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF, #DAD6E7);  
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#FFFFFF', EndColorStr='#DAD6E7', gradientType='1'); /* IE6 - IE9 */
}
```

becomes this:

```
.label
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 10pt;
    text-align: right;
    color: black;
    vertical-align: top;
    padding-left: .5em;

    background-color: #EBEBEB; /* Fallback background color for non supported browsers */  
    background-image: linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF, #DAD6E7);  
}
```

and strips out my styles. Additionally, the CSS version in the style sheet toolbar shows 2.1 after I had explicity set to 3.0 not long ago.

Any idea why VS2010 keeps downgrading my CSS verison to 2.1 and removing non-IE styles?

Comment: Are they being removed from the actual file or are you not seeing them in the browser viewer? If you just don't see them in the browser that is because the browser will ignore those styles that are not pertinent.

Comment: No, its actually removing them from the file.

Comment: @djmadscribbler - yep, dup posting, but the other one didn't have a solution either. Although it did oddly enough use the same filter style in the example. Says it happens when you save files that "include" the CSS file, which would mean a master page or something. I did notice that the CSS toolbar selector gets downgraded to 2.1 when I start debugging, but that's not when it deletes my sytles.

Comment: I found a workaround in the other original post. See my answer there.