# CSS file keeps changing

Tags: visual-studio, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following CSS in my `main.css` file:

```
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #aaaaaa) !important;
background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#eeeeee), to(#aaaaaa)) !important;
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #aaaaaa) !important;
background-image:-o-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #aaaaaa) !important;
background-image:linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #aaaaaa) !important;
background-repeat:repeat-x;
filter:progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffeeeeee', endColorstr='#ffaaaaaa', GradientType=0) !important;
```

Which keeps changing itself to:

```
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #eeeeee, #aaaaaa) !important;
```

Why could this be happening? The selector is `.navbar .nav` which is defined in another CSS file too, the Bootstrap CSS file. Could it be that Visual Studio is automatically cleaning up duplicate definitions or something?

**edit:** It changes every few builds. I can't pinpoint what action is causing it to automatically change.

Comment: Do you have a main.less file in your project?

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456244/visual-studio-deletes-css-properties or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10195951/vs2010-keeps-removing-non-ie-styles-in-css-and-downgrades-verison-from-3-0-to-2

Comment: @user982119 I tried running your CSS a few times in Visual Studio 2012 and I've had no problems. Can you provide more info? What kind of project is it? What version of Visual Studio is this?

Answer (score 1):

Those are browser based CSS tags:

This only works in mozilla:

```
background-image:-moz-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #aaaaaa) !important;
```

Works in Chrome/Webkit based browsers:

```
background-image:-webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#eeeeee), to(#aaaaaa)) !important;
background-image:-webkit-linear-gradient(top, #eeeeee, #aaaaaa) !important;
```

Actually this cross browser technique is somewhat deprecated in the release of CSS3. You need to find the corresponding CSS that works on the browser you are using.

It's not 'changing' just that, other CSS was ignored by the browser.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look to see if there are any [build events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ke5z92ks.aspx)  setup in Visual Studio. It's possible the project has been configured to run something like csstidy or a css minimizer that is attempting to cleanup duplicate properties.

Alternatively, if you're using source control (which I would hope you are), your source control may be configured to run a commit hook that does the same sort of thing. How that is configured will depend on the source control that you're using.

I wouldn't expect this to be a problem with a modern version of csstidy (or any other modern css optimising tool for that matter). However, if this is a project that you've inherited, it's possible it was setup some time ago with a tool that is now out of date.

Comment: I am using source control (SVN), but the file changes itself every few commits. Again, still can't pinpoint what is causing it to change. I created the project from scratch - I used initializr. And then I have a main.css file which is the one that changes. It's not a huge issue, as long as it doesn't happen outside of the dev environment :P, thanks for the suggestions, I'll check the build events..

Comment: Having just read the links that Bass Jobsen posted in the comments, I'm beginning to think it's more likely a problem in Visual Studio itself - possibly something to do with CSS auto formatting. Is it possible it's triggered when you perform a paste operation somewhere in the file?