# missing an opening brace '({)' after the selector in the style rule

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, css

Programming in ASP.NET 4.0 and I thought I would start with CSS3 on one of my client site.

I first made a fiddle which worked beautifully. Styles used in the fiddle are

```
.newmainblock{
    background:rgb(254,254,253) ; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,254,253,1) 0%, rgba(220,227,196,1) 42%, rgba(174,191,118,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(254,254,253,1)), color-stop(42%,rgba(220,227,196,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(174,191,118,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,254,253,1) 0%,rgba(220,227,196,1) 42%,rgba(174,191,118,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,254,253,1) 0%,rgba(220,227,196,1) 42%,rgba(174,191,118,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,254,253,1) 0%,rgba(220,227,196,1) 42%,rgba(174,191,118,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(254,254,253,1) 0%,rgba(220,227,196,1) 42%,rgba(174,191,118,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fefefd', endColorstr='#aebf76',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    border: 1px solid #000000;
    height: 440px;
}​


#newbuttonbar {     
    background: rgb(180,221,180); /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(180,221,180,1) 0%, rgba(131,199,131,1) 17%, rgba(82,177,82,1) 33%, rgba(0,138,0,1) 67%, rgba(0,87,0,1) 83%, rgba(0,36,0,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(180,221,180,1)), color-stop(17%,rgba(131,199,131,1)), color-stop(33%,rgba(82,177,82,1)), color-stop(67%,rgba(0,138,0,1)), color-stop(83%,rgba(0,87,0,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,36,0,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(180,221,180,1) 0%,rgba(131,199,131,1) 17%,rgba(82,177,82,1) 33%,rgba(0,138,0,1) 67%,rgba(0,87,0,1) 83%,rgba(0,36,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(180,221,180,1) 0%,rgba(131,199,131,1) 17%,rgba(82,177,82,1) 33%,rgba(0,138,0,1) 67%,rgba(0,87,0,1) 83%,rgba(0,36,0,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(180,221,180,1) 0%,rgba(131,199,131,1) 17%,rgba(82,177,82,1) 33%,rgba(0,138,0,1) 67%,rgba(0,87,0,1) 83%,rgba(0,36,0,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(180,221,180,1) 0%,rgba(131,199,131,1) 17%,rgba(82,177,82,1) 33%,rgba(0,138,0,1) 67%,rgba(0,87,0,1) 83%,rgba(0,36,0,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b4ddb4', endColorstr='#002400',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */    
}​
```

( [Demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/codovations/CSDSq/) )

Now I copied that to my css inside my visual studio and ran it. To my dismay I found that I could not see a `newbuttonbar` at all. I asked firebug and they told me there is no `newbuttonbar` defined at all.

[image]

Also even though the style is not applied its still displayed in Firebug CSS console

[image]

At last I found the reason as this. ( *I am not sure if this is correct* )
The CSS editor complains that `newmainblock` is

> missing an opening brace '({)' after the selector in the style rule

So it omits the tag that just comes after `newmainblock`. That is `newbuttonbar`. All the other styles are taken into account. Why this happens, what am I doing wrong and how to correct it?

On an unrelated sidenote DTD of my ASP.NET generated page as well as my fiddle is XHTMl1.0

Comment: The only thing I can see is there is not a space between `newmainblock` and the opening brace.  I've seen stranger things happen.

Comment: @RobertHarvey: no, its not. if i place both at the bottom of two different stylesheets they will work beautifully. plus if i give a simple unwanted style like `#fun1{margin: 0}` below each of the style rules then also it works like a charm. and thats the workaround i have done now.

Comment: When I pasted your CSS into Dreamweaver it was showing a strange character after each of your two block's closing brackets. I.E after this character "}". Try deleting back to that character (on each of your two blocks of code) and see if that helps.

Comment: @BillyMoat: did not work.good suggestion. thanks.

Comment: If you remove the whole of newmainblock does it work still throw an error? Best suggestion is to remove code line by line until no error is thrown then you'll know where it's going wrong.

Comment: @Billy Moat: thanks a lot. the problem was with a curly brace with some other encoding. sorry, i did not correct thoroughly earlier....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some invalid characters in your CSS after the closing curly braces. Your code editor just isn't showing them. Try the page in Chrome, then open the web inspector (F12). Switch to the "Resources" or "Sources" tab and take a look at your CSS. You'll see what I mean.

Here's the fixed CSS:

```
.newmainblock{
    background:rgb(254,254,253) ; /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,254,253,1) 0%, rgba(220,227,196,1) 42%, rgba(174,191,118,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(254,254,253,1)), color-stop(42%,rgba(220,227,196,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(174,191,118,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,254,253,1) 0%,rgba(220,227,196,1) 42%,rgba(174,191,118,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,254,253,1) 0%,rgba(220,227,196,1) 42%,rgba(174,191,118,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(254,254,253,1) 0%,rgba(220,227,196,1) 42%,rgba(174,191,118,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(254,254,253,1) 0%,rgba(220,227,196,1) 42%,rgba(174,191,118,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#fefefd', endColorstr='#aebf76',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */

    border: 1px solid #000000;
    height: 440px;
}
#newbuttonbar {     
    background: rgb(180,221,180); /* Old browsers */
    /* IE9 SVG, needs conditional override of 'filter' to 'none' */
    background: url(data:image/svg+xml;base64,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);
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(180,221,180,1) 0%, rgba(131,199,131,1) 17%, rgba(82,177,82,1) 33%, rgba(0,138,0,1) 67%, rgba(0,87,0,1) 83%, rgba(0,36,0,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(180,221,180,1)), color-stop(17%,rgba(131,199,131,1)), color-stop(33%,rgba(82,177,82,1)), color-stop(67%,rgba(0,138,0,1)), color-stop(83%,rgba(0,87,0,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(0,36,0,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(180,221,180,1) 0%,rgba(131,199,131,1) 17%,rgba(82,177,82,1) 33%,rgba(0,138,0,1) 67%,rgba(0,87,0,1) 83%,rgba(0,36,0,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(180,221,180,1) 0%,rgba(131,199,131,1) 17%,rgba(82,177,82,1) 33%,rgba(0,138,0,1) 67%,rgba(0,87,0,1) 83%,rgba(0,36,0,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgba(180,221,180,1) 0%,rgba(131,199,131,1) 17%,rgba(82,177,82,1) 33%,rgba(0,138,0,1) 67%,rgba(0,87,0,1) 83%,rgba(0,36,0,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(180,221,180,1) 0%,rgba(131,199,131,1) 17%,rgba(82,177,82,1) 33%,rgba(0,138,0,1) 67%,rgba(0,87,0,1) 83%,rgba(0,36,0,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#b4ddb4', endColorstr='#002400',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-8 */    
}
```