# CSS changes by itself

Tags: css, visual-studio-2008

I have a CSS stylesheet used in one of my web forms in an ASP.NET project.

I am working in **Visual Studio 2008**

Many times, when I make some change to it, it changes one of my CSS classes, resulting in some ugly borders.

For example: I make a change, save the stylesheet, continue working on some other page, then I notice the stylesheet needs to be saved again. I have to go back to the stylesheet, press *Undo* and then save it again.

I was curious about what changes, so I copied and compared the text before and after the undo, this is what changes:

[image]

**EDIT:** Right now, the moment I open the `.css` file by double clicking it in the solution explorer, it immidiately changes my css and needs to be saved. Extremely annoying.

Comment: I've never used Visual Studio before, however, if I had to guess I would say that perhaps because you are using border and border-raidus it's somehow getting confused and overwriting the border property. Maybe try breaking out the css into individual properties like border-color, border-width, etc.

Comment: Are you sure this file isn't opened in another program that maybe saves it automatically? Or in something like FileZilla where it is synchronised with a server?

Comment: Yes pretty sure. And it is because of the CSS, because I used the same css code in other projects too and i got the same problem. @Somebody

Comment: Don't double click on solution explorer. Try 'Check-Out for Edit..' and choose lock type to `Check-out` so noone else can edit (and probably overwrite) what you did.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL I'm not working with with Version Control Workspaces

Comment: @enb081 Ah, sorry then.

Answer (score 3):

What now follows is not my answer, but it is the best possible thing I could find, and now 
 guess were I found it? Yes, right here in StackOverFlow
Here's the Link: [Visual Studio (2012 and lower) deletes CSS properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456244/visual-studio-deletes-css-properties)
I really hope it helps


"
The existence of the "filter:" style is what's causing all of the "background-image:" styles to disappear except the last one listed. It's not that it's removing what it doesn't know, it's just removing all but the last "background-image" style listed. Must be Microsoft (intended) way of making filter and an MS specific background-image style play nicely together, however they didn't code it up very well. Definitely a MS VS defect. To repro, just right click in the CSS class that has code similar to this:

```
background-color: #EBEBEB; /* Fallback background color for non supported browsers */  
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#FFFFFF), to(#DAD6E7));  
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF, #DAD6E7);  
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF, #DAD6E7);  
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF, #DAD6E7);  
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF, #DAD6E7);  
background-image: linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF, #DAD6E7);  
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startCol
```

orStr='#FFFFFF', EndColorStr='#DAD6E7', gradientType='1'); /* IE6 - IE9 */
and then select "Build Style...". Then click "OK" without changing anything and watch it remove all but the last background-image left. Try changing the order of the "background-image styles and leave webkit last and then see for yourself.

You'll notice that if you remove the "filter:" style the problem goes away, however we need that (for this example) so the solution seems to be moving the "filter:" style above all the "background-image:" lines. Once you do that, it leaves them alone and the problem goes away.

Changing the above CSS to this seems to aleviate the problem:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#FFFFFF', EndColorStr='#DAD6E7', gradientType='1'); /* IE6 - IE9 */
background-color: #EBEBEB; /* Fallback background color for non supported browsers */  
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, right top, from(#FFFFFF), to(#DAD6E7));  
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF, #DAD6E7);  
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF, #DAD6E7);  
background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF, #DAD6E7);  
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF, #DAD6E7);  
background-image: linear-gradient(left, #FFFFFF, #DAD6E7);
```

**UPDATE:** The workaround above only works for when VS applies formatting when you're using the "Build Style..." --> "Modify Style" dialog because I just saw it again with the fix above in place so it must be from somthing else.
"

Comment: Haven't tested this answer but the post the solution comes from seems to be good lead! :)

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried another Visual Studio version. Like 2010 or 2012.

Here the problem is that is reordering a few lines of code, but it seems here to be a problem from something else then Visual Studio. Try a reinstall. If you like VS style so much you could try a higher version. Advantages: A lot of bug fixed and lots of features added.

My recommendation: Try SublimeText2 for a while and see if you like it. I love it and it is a lot faster than VS. Give it a try. It worth.

Comment: I am developing in ASP.NET, I have to use Visual Studio.

Comment: The problem is not only reordering, it also removes the border properties.

Comment: Now i see it removes even text shadow. Maybe the VS 2008 doesn't recognize text shadow, but i don't get the border problem. I will dig in to try finding the problem, but no promises. Meanwhile you could try a reinstall the VS 2008 or try 2010 or 2012.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your environment, so I can't say if something else is changing your CSS. If I were you, I would try opening the file with another editor, maybe two, just to find out if the blame is on Virtual Studio 2008.

If it turns out it *is* Virtual Studio's fault *and* you don't have an ultimate *need* to stick to using it, I would recommend [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/). It's very powerful and it's free.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

From the `toolbar`,
**Options->HTML Designer->CSS Styling**, change **"Auto Style Application"** to **"Manual Style Application"**

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is as dense as me.

I had the same issue and it was because I had opened the css from the bin folder!