# .NET and Twitter Bootstrap buttons

Tags: .net, css, twitter-bootstrap

I seem to be experiencing some wierdness in VS2012 when using a portion of Twitter's Bootstrap CSS; occasionaly the button styles seem to get modified without my action...

Here is the original code from Bootstrap:

```
    .btn {
display: inline-block;
*display: inline;
/* IE7 inline-block hack */
*zoom: 1;
padding: 4px 12px;
margin-bottom: 0;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 20px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
cursor: pointer;
color: #333333;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
background-color: #f5f5f5;
background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%, from(#ffffff), to(#e6e6e6));
background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #e6e6e6);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#ffffffff', endColorstr='#ffe6e6e6', GradientType=0);
border-color: #e6e6e6 #e6e6e6 #bfbfbf;
border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
*background-color: #e6e6e6;
/* Darken IE7 buttons by default so they stand out more given they won't have borders */
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(enabled = false);
border: 1px solid #cccccc;
*border: 0;
border-bottom-color: #b3b3b3;
-webkit-border-radius: 4px;
-moz-border-radius: 4px;
border-radius: 4px;
*margin-left: .3em;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,.2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0,0,0,.05);
}
```

and here is what (i assume) .NET is doing to it:

```
btn {
display: inline-block;
*border-bottom: 0 none #b3b3b3; display: inline;
/* IE7 inline-block hack */
*zoom: 1;
padding: 4px 12px;
margin-bottom: 0;
font-size: 14px;
line-height: 20px;
text-align: center;
vertical-align: middle;
cursor: pointer;
color: #333333;
text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.75);
background-color: #f5f5f5;
background-repeat: repeat-x;
border-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1) rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
*-webkit-border-radius: 4px; -moz-border-radius: 4px; border-radius: 4px; margin-left: .3em;    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05); -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05); box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .2), 0 1px 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, .05); background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #ffffff, #e6e6e6); /* Darken IE7 buttons by default so they stand out more given they won't have borders */

**border-left-style: none; border-left-color: inherit; border-left-width: 0; border-right-style: none; border-right-color: inherit; border-right-width: 0; border-top-style: none; border-top-color: inherit; border-top-width: 0; }
```

Has anyone experienced this issue before? it seems to be related to the specific hacks that bootstrap contains but I seem unable to stop it from happening....

**EDIT 10/07/13:**

Seems that this behaviour is a bug/feature of VS2010/12...

[Visual Studio (2012 and lower) deletes CSS properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456244/visual-studio-deletes-css-properties)

My current workaround is to not open the css file in .NET; which sucks...

Comment: Aside if you have something in your css overriding your btn element or classes, there's no reason things should change. Something seems to get injected somewhere along the line or modified.  Do you use bootstrap or just copied the button part. I have some custom css "inspired" from bootstrap but without all the hacks if you like ..but it's just for buttons

Comment: it is an extract from the main bootstrap css file; I only require the buttons.

Comment: Just a thought - do you have any extensions installed that could be responsible?

Comment: Good shout; I had Mindscape Web Workbench installed; I've reset the dev environment back to a vanilla installation on a VM; i'll see if a reset resolves it.

Comment: @Bomski You can try to disable "Mindscape Web Workbench" in plugin-manager and I hope problem will got solved.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer, but i had the same issues with not liking the CSS hacks bootstrap uses for browsers, so i took their nice icons and rewrote the button part.

However as you can see this still uses LESS. Which is availible in VS2012 via "Web Essentials 2012" from a MS team member

Usage

```
 <a class="button oval x-large black" href="/path"><i class="icon icon-ok-sign"></i> click here</a>
```

CSS

```
.icon {
    background: url("/content/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings-white.png?@{timestamp}") no-repeat top left;
    width: 14px;
    height: 14px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin: 0 0 1px 0;
    /*IE7 FIX */
    display: inline;
    display: inline-block;

    &.black { background: url("/content/bootstrap/img/glyphicons-halflings.png?@{timestamp}") no-repeat top left; }
    &.chat { background-position: 0 0; }
    &.mail { background-position: 0 -27px; }

    /* Bootstrap icons */
    &.icon-glass { background-position: 0 0; }
    &.icon-music { background-position: -24px 0; }
    &.icon-search { background-position: -48px 0; }
    &.icon-envelope { background-position: -72px 0; }
    &.icon-heart { background-position: -96px 0; }
    &.icon-star { background-position: -120px 0; }
    &.icon-star-empty { background-position: -144px 0; }
    &.icon-user { background-position: -168px 0; }
    &.icon-film { background-position: -192px 0; }
    &.icon-th-large { background-position: -216px 0; }
    &.icon-th { background-position: -240px 0; }
    &.icon-th-list { background-position: -264px 0; }
    &.icon-ok { background-position: -288px 0; }
    &.icon-remove { background-position: -312px 0; }
    &.icon-zoom-in { background-position: -336px 0; }
    &.icon-zoom-out { background-position: -360px 0; }
    &.icon-off { background-position: -384px 0; }
    &.icon-signal { background-position: -408px 0; }
    &.icon-cog { background-position: -432px 0; }
    &.icon-trash { background-position: -456px 0; }
    &.icon-home { background-position: 0 -24px; }
    &.icon-file { background-position: -24px -24px; }
    &.icon-time { background-position: -48px -24px; }
    &.icon-road { background-position: -72px -24px; }
    &.icon-download-alt { background-position: -96px -24px; }
    &.icon-download { background-position: -120px -24px; }
    &.icon-upload { background-position: -144px -24px; }
    &.icon-inbox { background-position: -168px -24px; }
    &.icon-play-circle { background-position: -192px -24px; }
    &.icon-repeat { background-position: -216px -24px; }
    &.icon-refresh { background-position: -240px -24px; }
    &.icon-list-alt { background-position: -264px -24px; }
    &.icon-lock { background-position: -287px -24px; }
    &.icon-flag { background-position: -312px -24px; }
    &.icon-headphones { background-position: -336px -24px; }
    &.icon-volume-off { background-position: -360px -24px; }
    &.icon-volume-down { background-position: -384px -24px; }
    &.icon-volume-up { background-position: -408px -24px; }
    &.icon-qrcode { background-position: -432px -24px; }
    &.icon-barcode { background-position: -456px -24px; }
    &.icon-tag { background-position: 0 -48px; }
    &.icon-tags { background-position: -25px -48px; }
    &.icon-book { background-position: -48px -48px; }
    &.icon-bookmark { background-position: -72px -48px; }
    &.icon-print { background-position: -96px -48px; }
    &.icon-camera { background-position: -120px -48px; }
    &.icon-font { background-position: -144px -48px; }
    &.icon-bold { background-position: -167px -48px; }
    &.icon-italic { background-position: -192px -48px; }
    &.icon-text-height { background-position: -216px -48px; }
    &.icon-text-width { background-position: -240px -48px; }
    &.icon-align-left { background-position: -264px -48px; }
    &.icon-align-center { background-position: -288px -48px; }
    &.icon-align-right { background-position: -312px -48px; }
    &.icon-align-justify { background-position: -336px -48px; }
    &.icon-list { background-position: -360px -48px; }
    &.icon-indent-left { background-position: -384px -48px; }
    &.icon-indent-right { background-position: -408px -48px; }
    &.icon-facetime-video { background-position: -432px -48px; }
    &.icon-picture { background-position: -456px -48px; }
    &.icon-pencil { background-position: 0 -72px; }
    &.icon-map-marker { background-position: -24px -72px; }
    &.icon-adjust { background-position: -48px -72px; }
    &.icon-tint { background-position: -72px -72px; }
    &.icon-edit { background-position: -96px -72px; }
    &.icon-share { background-position: -120px -72px; }
    &.icon-check { background-position: -144px -72px; }
    &.icon-move { background-position: -168px -72px; }
    &.icon-step-backward { background-position: -192px -72px; }
    &.icon-fast-backward { background-position: -216px -72px; }
    &.icon-backward { background-position: -240px -72px; }
    &.icon-play { background-position: -264px -72px; }
    &.icon-pause { background-position: -288px -72px; }
    &.icon-stop { background-position: -312px -72px; }
    &.icon-forward { background-position: -336px -72px; }
    &.icon-fast-forward { background-position: -360px -72px; }
    &.icon-step-forward { background-position: -384px -72px; }
    &.icon-eject { background-position: -408px -72px; }
    &.icon-chevron-left { background-position: -432px -72px; }
    &.icon-chevron-right { background-position: -456px -72px; }
    &.icon-plus-sign { background-position: 0 -96px; }
    &.icon-minus-sign { background-position: -24px -96px; }
    &.icon-remove-sign { background-position: -48px -96px; }
    &.icon-ok-sign { background-position: -72px -96px; }
    &.icon-question-sign { background-position: -96px -96px; }
    &.icon-info-sign { background-position: -120px -96px; }
    &.icon-screenshot { background-position: -144px -96px; }
    &.icon-remove-circle { background-position: -168px -96px; }
    &.icon-ok-circle { background-position: -192px -96px; }
    &.icon-ban-circle { background-position: -216px -96px; }
    &.icon-arrow-left { background-position: -240px -96px; }
    &.icon-arrow-right { background-position: -264px -96px; }
    &.icon-arrow-up { background-position: -289px -96px; }
    &.icon-arrow-down { background-position: -312px -96px; }
    &.icon-share-alt { background-position: -336px -96px; }
    &.icon-resize-full { background-position: -360px -96px; }
    &.icon-resize-small { background-position: -384px -96px; }
    &.icon-plus { background-position: -408px -96px; }
    &.icon-minus { background-position: -433px -96px; }
    &.icon-asterisk { background-position: -456px -96px; }
    &.icon-exclamation-sign { background-position: 0 -120px; }
    &.icon-gift { background-position: -24px -120px; }
    &.icon-leaf { background-position: -48px -120px; }
    &.icon-fire { background-position: -72px -120px; }
    &.icon-eye-open { background-position: -96px -120px; }
    &.icon-eye-close { background-position: -120px -120px; }
    &.icon-warning-sign { background-position: -144px -120px; }
    &.icon-smiley { width: 15px; background-position: -167px -120px; }
    &.icon-calendar { background-position: -192px -120px; }
    &.icon-paperclip { background-position: -217px -120px; }
    &.icon-comment { background-position: -240px -120px; }
    &.icon-magnet { background-position: -264px -120px; }
    &.icon-chevron-up { background-position: -288px -120px; }
    &.icon-chevron-down { background-position: -313px -119px; }
    &.icon-retweet { background-position: -336px -120px; }
    &.icon-shopping-cart { background-position: -360px -120px; }
    &.icon-folder-close { background-position: -384px -120px; }
    &.icon-folder-open { width: 16px; background-position: -408px -120px; }
    &.icon-resize-vertical { background-position: -432px -119px; }
    &.icon-resize-horizontal { background-position: -456px -118px; }
    &.icon-hdd { background-position: 0 -144px; }
    &.icon-bullhorn { background-position: -24px -144px; }
    &.icon-bell { background-position: -48px -144px; }
    &.icon-certificate { background-position: -72px -144px; }
    &.icon-thumbs-up { background-position: -96px -144px; }
    &.icon-thumbs-down { background-position: -120px -144px; }
    &.icon-hand-right { background-position: -144px -144px; }
    &.icon-hand-left { background-position: -168px -144px; }
    &.icon-hand-up { background-position: -192px -144px; }
    &.icon-hand-down { background-position: -216px -144px; }
    &.icon-circle-arrow-right { background-position: -240px -144px; }
    &.icon-circle-arrow-left { background-position: -264px -144px; }
    &.icon-circle-arrow-up { background-position: -288px -144px; }
    &.icon-circle-arrow-down { background-position: -312px -144px; }
    &.icon-globe { background-position: -336px -144px; }
    &.icon-wrench { background-position: -360px -144px; }
    &.icon-tasks { background-position: -384px -144px; }
    &.icon-filter { background-position: -408px -144px; }
    &.icon-briefcase { background-position: -432px -144px; }
    &.icon-fullscreen { background-position: -456px -144px; }
}

/* BUTTONS */
.button, .button:visited, .button:link {
    /*IE7 FIX */
    display: inline;
    display: inline-block;
    color: @button-one-text;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-variant: small-caps;
}

.button {
    background-color: @button-one;
    padding: 5px 15px;
    font-size: 12px;

    &:hover { background-color: @button-one-hover; }

    /* Size Variations */
    &.small { font-size: 11px; padding: 2px 10px; }

    &.large { font-size: 22px; padding: 10px 15px; }
    &.x-large { font-size: 30px; padding: 10px 15px; }

    /* Form Variations */
    &.rounded { border-radius: 5px; }

    &.oval { border-radius: 12px; }
    /* Color Variations */
    &.black {
        background-color: @button-two;

        &:hover { background-color: @button-two-hover; }
        &.member-false { background-color: @button-two-inactive; }
    }

    &.green {
        background-color: @button-three;

        &:hover { background-color: @button-three-hover; }
        &.member-false { background-color: @button-three-inactive; }
    }
}
```